# How do I switch between Gmail tabs using keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

Now that Gmail has rolled out tab groupings of my email, I have two (or more) additional places to clear of new messages.

[image: Gmail tabs]

Unfortunately, in their tour of the feature, they didn't seem to mention any keyboard shortcuts to use. As well, there isn't any mention in the keyboard shortcut window.

[image: Shortcuts help window]

Are there any ways to switch between these tabs without resorting to the mouse?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

<kbd>~</kbd> - move to previous tab (left, looping to far right)

<kbd>`</kbd> - move to next tab (right, looping to far left)

[image: Shortcut/arrow annotated Gmail tabs]

In a complete accident, I found one of the shortcuts while typing up the question and taking screenshots. I tried to switch Chrome windows with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (Mac), but dropped off <kbd>Cmd</kbd> too soon. The flip version, was a quick matter of trial and error.

*Edit:*

Looks like this is now officially in the keyboard shortcuts help screen. They refer to these not as tabs, but as "inbox sections".

[image: Inbox section switch keyboard shortcuts]

Comment: The forward shortcut was not working for me, I discovered the fix is to disable the 'Multiple Inboxes' Lab.

Comment: Still does not work for me. Multiple Inboxes is disabled too. Any ideas?

Comment: @FlavioWuensche The ` and ~ keys might be both be so-called 'dead keys' (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) on your keyboard layout as they are on mine. In that case you will need to press a space after the ~ or ` to make it work.

Comment: On the macbook for me it works only to the right with Shift+option+`, without spacebar (no deadkey)